# Julia is not giving me a good return value in Binary Search

Tags: search, binary, julia

I have made this recursive binary search function in Julia that will return the index where the number I am looking for is. (example: array = [1,2,4,8,16], key = 8, output = 4 ), but the output it gives me is -1 every time (that should only be the case if the number does not exist). Here is the code

```
function binary(A, key)
   return binarystep(A, 1, length(A), key)
end

function binarystep(A, p, r, key)
if p > r
    return -1
else
        q = Int(floor((p+r)/2))
        if A[q] == key
            return q
        elseif A[q] < key
            return binarystep(A, p, q-1, key)
        else 
            return binarystep(A,q+1, r, key)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `A[q] > key` if you assume `A` is non-decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to change the order you are looking at it.

Instead of

```
elseif A[q] < key
    return binarystep(A, p, q-1, key)
else 
    return binarystep(A,q+1, r, key)
end
```

You should just change `A[q] > key`. You wrote it to find a value inside a decreasing array. You could generalize it more by passing it a comparator (used for the sorting) and then use its value for finding if the value should go up or down. Like:

`comparator = cpm(A[q], value);`

And use this value to do the if:

```
q = Int(floor((p+r)/2));
comparator = cpm(A[q], value);
if comparator === 0
    return q
elseif comparator < 0
    return binarystep(A, p, q-1, key)
else
    return binarystep(A, q+1, r, key)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A side note. The binary search is already implemented in Julia through a set of `searchsorted` functions (`searchsorted`,`searchsortedfirst`, `searchsortedlast`).
For an example:

```
julia> searchsortedfirst([1,2,4,8,16], 4)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different implementation with comments and more expressive names. The main error in your code is `elseif A[q] < key` as pointed out by others.

```
binary_search(A, target) = binary_search(A, 1, length(A), target)

function binary_search(A, left, right, target)
    
    left > right && return -1
    
    mid = (left + right) ÷ 2
 
    # Base condition (a target is found)
    if A[mid] == target
        return mid
 
    # discard all elements in the right search space,
    # including the middle element
    elseif A[mid] > target
        binary_search(A, left, mid - 1, target)
 
    # discard all elements in the left search space,
    # including the middle element
    else
        binary_search(A, mid + 1, right, target)
    end 
end
```

Test:

```
A = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
target = 8
binary_search(A, target)
 4
```